# Quartz job scheduler using Java, stuck on standby mode without the job being executed

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

i have a class where i perform some activities, and i want to create a job that will handle this operation automatically, scheduled every x minutes for example.
I am using Quartz, this class implements Job, and in my driver class i'm creating my jobdetail, scheduler and trigger and then starting it. However, the job isn't being executed, log info :

```
    NOT STARTED.
  Currently in standby mode.
  Number of jobs executed: 0
```

The code for the scheduler in my driver class:

```
try {

        JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(TestMkFPMJob.class).withIdentity("TestMkFPMJob").build();
        Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withSchedule(SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule().withIntervalInSeconds(Integer.parseInt(strTimeSched)).repeatForever()).build();


        SchedulerFactory schFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
        Scheduler sch = schFactory.getScheduler();
        sch.start();
        sch.scheduleJob(job, trigger);

            } 
      catch (SchedulerException e)
      {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Scheduler Error");
      }
```

With "TestMkFPMJob" being the job class where my operations are handled, and strTimeSched is already fetched and set as 120 fetched from

I've been looking for a similar issue but can't seem to find any tip to move forward, appreciate any.
Please note that this is my first time using Quartz/Job scheduling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The log entry with `NOT STARTED` is misleading, as it is shown whenever a `QuartzScheduler` instance is created. It does not mean that the jobs are not running. It is written after the line `Scheduler sch = schFactory.getScheduler();` is executed and the scheduler is started in the next line.

If I take your example and run it on my pc, it is working as designed:

```
public class Quartz {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(MyJob.class).withIdentity("myJob").build();
            Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withSchedule(SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule().withIntervalInSeconds(Integer.parseInt("10")).repeatForever()).build();

            SchedulerFactory schFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
            Scheduler sch = schFactory.getScheduler();
            sch.start();
            sch.scheduleJob(job, trigger);

        }
        catch (SchedulerException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Scheduler Error");
        }
    }
    public static class MyJob implements Job {
        @Override
        public void execute(JobExecutionContext jobExecutionContext) throws JobExecutionException {
            System.out.println("runnning job");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I see, tried that and it's working for every 2 minutes, i know where my problem is now, my execute function is actually empty in my job class, thank you

Comment: Above example it is also working fine for me. I think the NOT Started logs is misleading.